# How to make fonts look better on the mac?

Tags: mac

After I plugged in an external monitor, suddenly my Xcode fonts look really bad. It's like if font's are not antialiased very well. I have a 15" unibody MacBookPro. The monitor resolution is set to 1440 x 900 pixels.

I am very sure font's looked better BEFORE I plugged in that external monitor. At least, suddenly I feel they are bad. Something happened... A restart didn't help.

Is there an setting that affects how text is rendered?

Comment: You'll have to define "bad"

Comment: Screen captures?  What are you seeing that looks "bad"?

Comment: I restarted my mac again, and voilla: Fonts look great! Sorry I can't make a snapshot of the ugly fonts - but to be honest, I hope I won't have the chance again ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to System Preferences -> Displays -> Arrangements and uncheck Mirror Displays (just to be sure OS X isn't trying to match resolutions by stretching. If that doesn't help, go to Display and change the resolutions until you find the right match for your monitor.

It may just be that your external monitor (if it's meant to be a TV, for example) has very low resolution or is interlaced (in which case you'll notice a definite flicker). If that doesn't help, comment on this answer and I'll try to find another possible explanation.

Comment: unfortunately my display resolution is correct. The strange thing is, that all fonts look nice except the ones in Xcode IDE (iphone development).

Comment: Did you try adjusting the font face, size and other preferences under the XCode preferences?